# What is the reason for the MSpec library?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, mspec-ruby

I've been reading the [README for the MSpec project](https://github.com/rubyspec/mspec#readme), and though it does a lot of explaining about *what* it is and (what it is not) with several contrasts between itself and RSpec, there's nothing about ***why*** it exists. Would using RSpec (at the time of starting MSpec) have  caused problems in some way, or was it missing some features? Are these things still true? Could an extension have been (or be) written for RSpec that would do this? Is it something political?

There's obviously a lot of documentation and examples for RSpec, more features and more updates to the library, and since MSpec seems harder to use IMO (considering the differences in feature set and my own comfort level with RSpec) I'd be very interested if anyone knows the reasons. Perhaps that sounds critical, but that's not my point, I'm just trying to supply some context - there are likely to be good reasons for all of this and that's what I wish to find out.

Comment: FYI... slight naming collision with a .NET library for context/specification testing, [Machine Specifications](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications), but commonly called MSpec. I mention it because I came here by way of the 'mspec' tag RSS.

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean ok, thanks, I'll remove that. It wasn't clear from the description, I'll see if I can get that updated a bit.

Comment: Your call. `rspec` could be considered the appropriate "parent" tag, so it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the README:

> MSpec attempts to use the simplest Ruby language features so that beginning
>   Ruby implementations can run the Ruby specs.

This was designed for incomplete implementations (Specifically Rubinius) of the base Ruby language. It doesn't use all the language features of Ruby, so it's easier to bootstrap your implementation to the point where you can run mspec's.

If you aren't creating a new implementation for the Ruby language, then you shouldn't use this.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm actually updating the specs for Rubyspec, as I think I found a bug in an implementation, and hence, a hole in the specs. Thanks for the response, it's much appreciated.